# append an a expression containing a variable to a list in Python

Tags: python, list

the expected output of this code is [x**2,x+2] but when i try to  run it the system gives me an error saying that the variable 'x' is not  defined.how to fix this issue. I would like to get the map the expression  to a graph.

```
l=[1,2]
out=[]
for i in l:
    if i==1:
        y=x**2
        out.append(y)
    if i==2:
        y=x+2
        out.append(y)
        
print(out)
```

Comment: What do you think that `x` should be?

Answer (score 1):

At `y=x**2` you have used the variable x but you have not defined it, which is causing the error. I'm assuming you want it as a string, so just do `y="x**2"`.